Language Pop Up Firefox
I know this has been asked but yet to find an answer. Recently I'm getting the language pop up on my screen when using Mozilla Firefox, as per the attached photo. It is so annoying, seems to be linked to input fields but even pops up when using google.
I have a macbook pro, using Sonoma.


What worked for me was checking my keyboard and input sources settings under System Settings > Keyboard. I removed any unnecessary languages/input sources that I wasn’t using. Also, make sure that the shortcut for switching input sources isn’t being accidentally triggered. That sorted it out for me.
